# How to get DataGridView cell value?

Tags: clr

I need to compare my array string with DataGridView cell value

```
string z = DataGridView->Rows[e->RowIndex]->Cells[1]->Value.ToString();
```

I'm getting a problem:

> IntelliSense: expression must have class type

Comment: Despite the tag, this clearly isn't a question about the CLR. I can only guess that you are using C++/CLR & WPF, but can't be sure. You will generally get better answers and faster, when you use the correct tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer if anyone else needs solution here it is

```
String^ z = System::Convert::ToString(Grid_Darbuotojai->Rows[e->RowIndex]->Cells[1]->Value);
```